# let and flet in emacs lisp

Tags: binding, elisp

I don't know if you would call it the canonical formulation, but to bind a local function I am advised by the GNU manual to use 'flet':

```
(defun adder-with-flet (x)
  (flet ( (f (x) (+ x 3)) )
    (f x))
)
```

However, by accident I tried (after having played in Scheme for a bit) the following expression, where I bind a lambda expression to a variable using 'let', and it also works if I pass the function to mapcar*:

```
(defun adder-with-let (x)
  (let ( (f (lambda (x) (+ x 3))) )
    (car (mapcar* f (list x)) ))
)
```

And both functions work:

```
(adder-with-flet 3)   ==> 6
(adder-with-let 3) ==> 6
```

Why does the second one work? I cannot find any documentation where 'let' can be used to bind functions to symbols.

Comment: To anyone trying this out, note that `flet` might not be available in the version of emacs you are using, in which case try a `(require 'cl)` beforehand as mentioned below (`flet` is a CommonLisp thingy).

Comment: Which GNU manual recommends the use of `flet` here?

Comment: From Emacs 25.1.1 Describe Function: flet    This macro is obsolete since 24.3; use either `cl-flet' or `cl-letf'

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Unlike Scheme, Emacs Lisp is a *2-lisp*, which means that each symbol has two separate bindings: the value binding and the function binding.  In a function call `(a b c d)`, the first symbol (`a`) is looked up using a function binding, the rest (`b c d`) are looked up using the value binding.  Special form `let` creates a new (local) value binding, `flet` creates a new function binding.

Note that whether value or function binding is used for lookup depends on the *position* in the `(a b c d)` function call, not on the *type* of the looked-up value.  In particular, a value binding can resolve to function.

In your first example, you function-bind `f` (via `flet`), and then do a function lookup:

```
(f ...)
```

In your second example, you value-bind `f` to a function (via `let`), and then use a value lookup:

```
(... f ...)
```

Both work because you use the same kind of binding and lookup in each case.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp#Comparison_with_other_Lisps

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I see, it is a distinction between value-lookup and function-lookup. I was familiar with the convention of having separate namespaces for functions and variables but couldn't connect that with how a function bound as a variable could be called by mapcar*.

Answer (score 21):

I did a quick search of the Emacs lisp manual and couldn't find any reference to `'flet`, which isn't terribly surprising since that is a part of `cl` - the [common-lisp package](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/cl.html#Function-Bindings).

[`let`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Local-Variables.html) will do a local binding as well, but it won't bind to the ["function cell"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Symbol-Components.html) for that symbol.

i.e. This works:

```
(let ((myf (lambda (x) (list x x))))
  (eval (list myf 3)))
```

but

```
(let ((myf (lambda (x) (list x x))))
  (myf 3))
```

fails with the error: "Lisp error: (void-function myf)"

`flet` on the other hand, does do the binding to the function cell, so this works:

```
(flet ((myf (x) (list x x)))
  (myf 3))
```

Notice the difference being that `flet` allows you to use the symbol `myf` directly, whereas the `let` does not - you have to use some indirection to get the function out of the "value cell" and apply that appropriately.

In your example, the '`mapcar`' did the equivalent to my use of `'eval`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Together with zielaj's explanation I see how this 'eval' thing also works. Yes, flet appears to be in the cl extension; I had originally read that (require 'cl) was needed before using flet but I guess in the newer emacs this is no longer the case...

Comment: Before the `cl` extension was shipped with Emacs out of the box, how did people handle function definitions that needed to be declared with let-like semantics? Was it just accepted that eval is the way to do it?

Answer (score 10):

@d11wq there is `funcall' for this purpose. The following works:

```
(defun adder-with-let (x)
  (let ((f #'(lambda (x) (+ x 3))))
    (funcall f 3)))

(adder-with-let 3) ;=> 6
```

Comment: You deserve a kudos!!!

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to use `flet` if you do not want to.  You place a function in the function cell of a local symbol defined using `let` as in the following example:

```
(let ((ALocalSymbol))
  (fset 'ALocalSymbol (lambda (x) (* 2 x)))
  (ALocalSymbol 4)
  )
```

Evaluating this will return 8.  Do notice the quote in front of `ALocalSymbol` in `(let ((ALocalSymbol))...)`.  While `setq` quotes symbols, `fset` does not.

`flet` is a syntactic sugar of sorts.  Using a plain-old `let` to define nil-valued symbols, allows you to choose which "cell" of a symbol to set.  You could use `setq` to set the symbol's value cell or `fset` to set the function cell.

Hope this helps,

Pablo

Comment: This is entirely wrong, and binds the (single) global function cell for the interned symbol `ALocalSymbol`. (Only *value* cells are let-bound.) You could do this if you were creating a *new* (uninterned) symbol, instead of just let-binding (the value of) the interned symbol.

Comment: For clarity: This code defines a function `ALocalSymbol` in the global function namespace. If a function by that name was defined already, it is clobbered.

Comment: Note also that if you did create an uninterned symbol, `(ALocalSymbol 4)` would still be calling the interned symbol's function, so you would need to `funcall` (or similar) your uninterned symbol/function.

Comment: I just realized that you guys are correct. I ended up creating a global symbol!  Thnx for the clarification.  This actually explains why some code I had written does not work correctly.